# C++ - Read from .txt to int and string

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm trying to figure out how to read data from a text file to int and/or string but it's beyond my knowledge.

My text file is structured like this:

```
a: 1 b:  1 c: 1 d: 1 e: 1 f: 1 |
a: 2 b:  2 c: 2 d: 2 e: 2 f: 2 |
a: 3 b:  3 c: 3 d: 3 e: 3 f: 3 |
```

My plan is read each row (1 loop) and somehow tell the computer to read what is after the : to either a string or an int.

```
void load(Class &x) {
    int a;
    std::string b;
    int c;
    std::string d;
    int e;
    int f;

    std::string textFile;
    std::cout << "File Name: ";
    std::cin >> textFile;

    std::ifstream txtfile(textFile + ".txt");

    if (txtfile.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "File Loaded Successfully!" << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2 /*Number of rows in .txt file!*/; i++){
            // I want to read from .txt to a, b, c, d, e, f.
            x.add(a, b, c, d, e, f);
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "File could not be opened." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: the `operator >>` of a stream stops when it sees white space

Comment: Everything after `:` is an `int`. Why do you need to read it into a string?

Comment: how about the lengths of each line? are they all the same? if so, you could get the integers by picking them from the lines, e.g: `a = stoi(line[3])`. If not you could split each line by [space] and then extract your numbers...